# What does ${!#} mean in Shell scripting?

Tags: shell-script

Found this in an obfuscated malicious shell script, beginning with:

`${!#}${*^} <<<`...

Could not find any reference to `${!#}`, but when `echo`'d, it outputs `-bash`. Is this a secret referene to the running shell? Why there is an extra dash then?

Thanks!

Comment: In "shell scripting", that will expand to the PID of the last background command. In `bash` (and *only* in `bash`), `${!#}` is the last positional parameter obtained via "Indirect Expansion" (the `${!var}` syntax) of the the `$#` variable.

Comment: @mosvy That looks like an answer, not a clarification of the question. As you point out, it includes information missing from the current answer, which is exactly why the system allows multiple answers to one question.

Comment: Regarding the extra dash itself, refer to this answer: https://superuser.com/a/278865/560377

Answer (score 36, accepted):

This answer is `bash`-specific, because you tried the `echo` in `bash`.  Not all shells behave the same.

In `bash`, if `$var1` is `foo`, then `${!var1}` is the same as `$foo`. The `!` is [indirect expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html): it causes `bash` to retrieve from the given variable a *variable name* (`foo`) instead of a *value*.

Now replace `var1` with `#`. 
`$#` is the number of arguments. 
If `$#` is 0, `${!#}` is `$0`. 
If `$#` is 4, `${!#}` is `$4`. 
In other words, `${!#}` is the last positional parameter, no matter how many there positional parameters there are.

If there are no positional parameters, `$#` is `0`, so the result is `$0`, which is the name of the shell or script ([reference](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Special-Parameters.html#index-_00240)).  In your case, that was `bash` (plus a [leading `-`](https://superuser.com/questions/278859/dash-in-front-of-bash/278865#278865) meaning that it's a login shell).

Quick test:

```
$ echo ${!#}
-bash

$ set the quick brown fox

$ echo ${!#}
fox
```

Comment: Your answer only applies to `bash`, but you fail to mention that. In all the other shells, `${!#}` will expand to the PID of the last background command (`$!`) with a empty string removed from the beginning (the `${var#pat}` form of parameter expansions).

Comment: Comments are indeed for clarifying answers; while it's possible to assume bash, given the text in the question, it's certainly reasonable to (collaboratively!) edit this answer to indicate shell-specific behavior.